# my neovim setup but i dont know how to fix error

Tags: lua, neovim

hello i setup my neovim from 'https://github.com/craftzdog/dotfiles-public'.
but An error has occurred, and I don't know how to solve it. please help me!!

error is 'attempt to call field 'init_lsp_saga' (a nil value)'

lspsaga.rc.lua

```
local status, saga = pcall(require, "lspsaga")
if (not status) then return end

saga.init_lsp_saga {
  server_filetype_map = {
    typescript = 'typescript'
  }
}

local opts = { noremap = true, silent = true }
vim.keymap.set('n', '<C-j>', '<Cmd>Lspsaga diagnostic_jump_next<CR>', opts)
vim.keymap.set('n', 'K', '<Cmd>Lspsaga hover_doc<CR>', opts)
vim.keymap.set('n', 'gd', '<Cmd>Lspsaga lsp_finder<CR>', opts)
-- vim.keymap.set('i', '<C-k>', '<Cmd>Lspsaga signature_help<CR>', opts)
vim.keymap.set('i', '<C-k>', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.signature_help()<CR>', opts)
vim.keymap.set('n', 'gp', '<Cmd>Lspsaga peek_definition<CR>', opts)
vim.keymap.set('n', 'gr', '<Cmd>Lspsaga rename<CR>', opts)
```

how can i fix this error?

Answer (score 6):

since you're using the latest version (newer than 0.2.3 which has the following changes PR: https://github.com/glepnir/lspsaga.nvim/pull/586
see specific change [in init.lua](https://github.com/glepnir/lspsaga.nvim/commit/afbd5718ffd453662ada49e9c520df60efc8f444#diff-40f5296ccddd71714533f9f84f3dc94738621a2c4b330f6a3334c988b918f59cR126))

You need to do saga.setup instead of saga.init_lsp_sag and you should be good to go!

```
local status, saga = pcall(require, "lspsaga")
if (not status) then return end

saga.setup {
  server_filetype_map = {
    typescript = 'typescript'
  }
}
```

instead of

```
local status, saga = pcall(require, "lspsaga")
if (not status) then return end

saga.init_lsp_saga {
  server_filetype_map = {
    typescript = 'typescript'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

seems lsp-saga have break change
I use this commit and work well.

currently, lsp-saga have a lot of refactoring change, I prefer to use the old version til it is stable.
"lspsaga.nvim": {
"commit": "b7b4777"
},